# Adding dialog boxes in your application

Tags: android

How do I create a  dialog box with an exit button?

Comment: I literally just took your title and [googled it](https://www.google.lv/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20dialog%20box%20with%20exit%20button)

Comment: yaa actually try to do it

Comment: Do you actually need to be spoon fed?

Answer (score 0):

That's it

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create it like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Exit")
    .setMessage("sure to exit?")
    .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("no", null)
    .show();
```